# How to change web root on Mavericks (OS X)

Tags: apache, webserver, osx-mavericks

I've tried to change the web root location on OS X, but got the error You don't have permission to access this file on this server.

What have I done:

I've changed the httpd.conf located at /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Where its says `DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"`

I've changed it to `DocumentRoot "/Users/myuser/Documents/htdocs"`

Then changed permissions of htdoc `sudo chmod -R 777 htdocs` and also ownership (to match the ones of /Library/WebServer/Documents) `sudo chown -R root:wheel` htdocs

Restarted apache `sudo apachectl restart` but still got the error above.

What am I missing?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Directory` directive access to the directory in your `apache` configuration. Specifically you need

> ```
>     Order allow,deny
>     Allow from all
> ```

statements in the Directory block. More information on the Directory directive at [Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory).

```
<Directory "/Users/myuser/Documents/htdocs">
    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: hey mate, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it didn't work. I've added the block into httpd.conf, restarted apache and it still got the same error that I don't have permission to access the files.

Comment: ok my hunch is you also need the `Options` directive (you expect to see list of files / directories rather than the permissions denied response). See updated answer.

Comment: Still nothing I'm afraid. Just for the record I've copied the whole block and added at the bottom of the httpd.conf file and restarted apache. Then I commented the line DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents" and uncommented DocumentRoot "/Users/myuser/Documents/htdocs". After every change I restarted apache and tried. No luck. Also, I've tested to see if the server is working and it is. I can get into phpmyadmin fine

Comment: Do I need to restart the computer?

Comment: No - just Apache needs re-start. It must be perms on the DocumentRoot folder then. Re-instate `DocumentRoot` and re-start Apache. Then check perms on that folder. Your apache user must have read and execute permissions on DocumentRoot folder.

Comment: Do you know who is the apache user on OS X? I've changed the ownership and permission of my folder to match that of DocumentRoot but still no luck

Comment: see User directive in the config file - it's probably www or _www. Having read your post again (me Duh!) you already have set perms on htdocs to 777.

Comment: Note that perms on /Users/myuser/Documents must permit Apache to access. Check perms on this folder are at least 755. Then check directories above also.